# Automatically turn on GPS

Tags: android, gps

I googled about it and there were solutions regarding the exploitation of Power Manager Bug to resolve this issue. But as the bug has now been solved. So how can now I solve this issue of starting the GPS when the app starts?
Please help.

Comment: try with the solution I have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function :

```
private void turnGPSOn(){
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

Make a call for this function from the `onCreate()` method of your `activity`.

**OR :**

```
Intent intent=new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Thanks.

Comment: @skjindal93 are you testing with device? which os?

Comment: Yes I am testing with device. Android 2.3.6

Comment: @skjindal93 I just edited with another way to do this. Try with that.

Comment: It worked. The GPS started blinking on top. But I have read it somewhere that turning on GPS automatically doesn't work in Android 3+ versions.

Comment: @skjindal93 cant say about that without testing with Android 3+ versions. If so then you can set condition for sdk version and try alternate way also.